# Code obfuscation in IntellIJ 14

Tags: intellij-idea, proguard, obfuscation

I'm working on developing a Jar artifact on IntellIJ 14, and I'd like to know if there is an easy way of obfuscating the code prior to sending it to my clients. So far, everybody talks about IntelliGuard, but the plugin was only maintained up to IntellIJ12, and it throws an exception when trying it on the newest versions.

Another option that I have read about is ProGuard, but I cannot find an step to step manual on how to make it work with IntellIJ.

I'm very curious if someone knows how to make any of the two work on the new version of the IDE, or if the know of any other method of obfuscating my code.

Thanks,
Cris.

Comment: Hello, did you find a solution? I have the same problem.